# Create APEX session from PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-apex

I am attempting to use APEX API APEX_DATA_EXPORT from PL/SQL.

In order to execute EXPORT function, it seems an apex session must be active. So I should set that using procedure

```
APEX_SESSION.CREATE_SESSION (
   p_app_id   => 100,
   p_page_id  => 1,
   p_username => 'EXAMPLE' );
```

However, the workspace does not have any applications created. That is because I am not using APEX main tools, I only use the APIs from PL/SQL.

Is it necesssary to create an apex application to use procedure CREATE_SESSION?

If yes, it is possible to create one using PL/SQL? For example, something like APEX_APPLICATION.CREATE_APPLICATION ?

APEX version 22.1
Oracle db 19.16 standard edtion

Comment: This sounds like a reasonable idea to raise for consideration by the team - https://apex.oracle.com/ideas

Comment: I submitted the idea https://apex.oracle.com/ideas/FR-2833 - "PL/SQL API to create APEX application"

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is necessary for the workspace to have an application with at least one page so you can call create_session.

You don't need to create the application each time, you can create a blank application by logging into the workspace and clicking Create Application.

If you need to automate this process, export the application and include the SQL script for installing it in your script that builds the workspace.